# Как получить все объекты из ветки firebase c#

Tags: c#, firebase

Не могли бы вы подсказать как можно получить все из ветки в firebase database.
Например:
У меня есть такая ветка

Clients:
Nik:
money: 100,
Mary:
money: 100

и я хочу получить все объекты ветки Clients не зная их имен.

```json
{
  "Mary": {
    "Money": 100
  },
  "Nik": {
    "Money": 100
  }
}
```

Comment: А что за библиотека для доступа к Firebase у вас используется?

Comment: А что за библиотека для доступа к Firebase у вас используется? firesharp

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Класс для данных будет такой

```csharp
public class MoneyItem
{
     public int Money { get; set; }
}
```

Тогда получение данных будет примерно таким

```csharp
FirebaseResponse firebaseResponse = await client.GetAsync("Clients");
string jsonText = firebaseResponse.Body;
if (jsonText?.Length > 0)
{
    Dictionary<string, MoneyItem> clients = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Dictionary<string, MoneyItem>>(jsonText);
    // данные получены, можно использовать
    foreach (KeyValuePair<string, MoneyItem> pair in clients)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("{0} {1}", pair.Key, pair.Value.Money);
    }
}
```

Код не тестировал. Для десериализации использовал `Newtonsoft.Json`, но если у вас .NET Core, можете аналогичным образом использовать `System.Text.Json`.

Comment: Не получилось.
Скорее всего связано с неправильно понятой структурой. 
Не:
[{
  "name": "Nik"
  "money": 100
}...]

а:
{
  'Clients':
  {
    'Nik': 
    {
      'Money': 100
    },..
  }
}

Comment: @ВладДжема покажите точный текст Json ответа, добавьте его в вопрос. Поставьте точку останова на `if (jsonText?.Length > 0)` в отладчике посмотрите содержимое `jsonText`.

Comment: "{\"Mary\":{\"Money\":100},\"Nik\":{\"Money\":100}}"

Comment: @ВладДжема обновил ответ

Comment: спасибо большое негде не мог найти как это сделать